# How about using URI path variables for an HTTP POST?

Tags: api, http, rest, post, uri

I've searched a lot but I couldn't find the proper answer to my question regarding my conditions.
I'm building a REST API, and the case, which seems a border line case to me, is the following:

-I'm dealing with two entities, Users and Roles. An User can have multiple roles assigned.
-To assign a Role to a User, the Role must be already in the DataBase.
-To assign a Role to a User, the only thing needed is the 'code' of the role, that is a short string.
-The uri path template used now is:
--Users: localhost:8080/api/users
--Given User: localhost:8080/api/users/{userId}
--Roles of a given User: localhost:8080/api/users/{userId}/roles 

Now, to 'link' a given User with a given Role, two options come to my mind.
-The first is the one that sounds as best practice in any scenario, sending the post data in the body, perhaps as a JSON.
-The other one, sending it through the uri and with an empty body. For example, to link User with id U001 with role R001, one would have to post to the following uri sending no data in the body: localhost:8080/api/users/U001/roles/R001

The thing is that I don't mind using the first option, and it seems to be the best and most correct one, but in this particular case, I'm not sure wether it is better to send an almost empty body (because it only holds the role id, a very short string) posting it to 'localhost:8080/api/users/U001/roles' or skipping the body and just sending the role id through the uri as a path parameter like localhost:8080/api/users/U001/roles/R001

Thank you all in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with putting role in the URI.  Your intuition was on the right track.  I'd do it this way.

PUT: locahost:8080/api/users/{userid}/role/{roleId}

And here's why.

FIRST: The PUT verb is **Idempotent**.  In other words (taken straight from the spec)

> ... the side-effects of N > 0 identical requests is the same as for a single request.

Which is what I'd assume you want in this regard.  You don't want multiple records in your state storage for each instance of user & role.  A user should feel at ease making the same PUT request without adversely effecting (adding duplicate records) the system.

When doing the same thing with a POST I'd expect to have a new record created for every request.

SECOND: The PUT verb is supposed to identify a specific resource. (taken straight from the spec)

> ... PUT request identifies the entity enclosed with the request -- the user agent knows what URI is intended and the server MUST NOT attempt to apply the request to some other resource. If the server desires that the request be applied to a different URI,
>   it MUST send a 301 (Moved Permanently) response; the user agent MAY then make its own decision regarding whether or not to redirect the request.

What if role R102 becomes obsolete and R104 is preferred? Return a 301 (Moved Permanently) with a HEADER (Location : localhost:8080/api/users/{userid}/role/R104).

FINALLY: When everything works well. Return a 201 (Created) when created and a 200 (No Content) on every subsequent request to the same URI. If they provide a Role that is not in the system return a 501 (Not Implemented).

Answer (score 0):

Hmm - in this case - a POST with a 302 may be a bit messy.

Why not a very simple 'PUT'/'DELETE' with indeed the URIs suggested ?

With simple; 20X meaning succeeded, possibly some 30X to indicate it was already there - and anything else a fail ?